# How to add multiple layers of overlays with transparency to an image using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

How can I push down the triangle and include the content on top of the white circles? I'm trying to find a solution for creating a hero section that contains a background image with the three overlay shapes included as part of the image. On top of the overlays will be an h1, p and btn. I included a screenshot below on what the design is supposed to look like.

There are these three overlays:

1. Straight angled shape with 0% transparency at bottom.
2. Outer circle with transparency.
3. Inner circle with transparency.

Here's what I have so far. I included a snippet below and also have a working version on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/zYjgVpa?editors=1100). The circles are in the right place at bottom left.

[image]

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
svg {
  width: 628;
  height: 628:
}
.element {  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 628px;
  background: url(https://images-prod.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/AN_images/health-benefits-of-apples-1296x728-feature.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
.element:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;0
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
.circle-outer {
  cx: 200;
  cy: 720;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.6;
  r: 420;
  w: 628;
  h: 628;
}
.circle-inner {
  cx: 200;
  cy: 720;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.6;
  r: 400;
}
.hero-triangle {
  content: '';
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 8%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="hero-content">
    <h1>This belongs in circle</h1>
    <p>This belongs in circle too.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
    </div>
    <svg viewbox width="1000" height="580" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle class="circle-outer" />
      <circle class="circle-inner" />
      <polygon points="0,0 0,200 1000,200" style="fill:#fff;" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h4>Body content must be positioned right underneath hero image for all widths.</h4>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using CSS for this? A div with round corners, a border half transparent and a background color also transparent. For the triangle in the bottom a clip path on the parent element.

Comment: @chrwahl - I tried that approach but couldn't figure out how to overlay the circles, triangle and content.

Comment: What do you want it to look like on different viewports? Is the image always to exactly fit width wise or is it to be cropped so for example the knife always shows but the image doesn’t overflow the height or…?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mixing in a SVG element you could just use CSS to create the circle.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 628px;
  background: url(https://images-prod.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/AN_images/health-benefits-of-apples-1296x728-feature.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  bottom: -200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 1em;
}

.hero-content>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <div>
        <h1>This belongs in circle</h1>
        <p>This belongs in circle too.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h4>Body content must be positioned right underneath hero image for all widths.</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. One other issue to note that I didn't foresee when I originally posted this is that the hero content (h1, p, btn, etc.), which takes up much more space that depicted in the screenshot, needs to also appear on top of the white triangle. When I add content there, the content flows beneath the white triangle.

Answer (score 1):

As the circles are just decorative rather than adding meaning there is no need for them to be elements. It will be sufficient for them to be background-images.

Here is a simple snippet which places the content element and gives it two acckground-images, both with some transparency, making them circles using radial-gradients.

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  rmin-height: 628px;
  background: url(https://images-prod.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/AN_images/health-benefits-of-apples-1296x728-feature.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 80%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  aspect-ratio: 1296 / 728;
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: -12.5%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 0 65%, transparent 65% 100%), radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0 70%, transparent 70% 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  rjustify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hero-content h1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.hero-content p {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.hero-content button {
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>This belongs in circle</h1>
      <p>This belongs in circle too.</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button>
    </div>
    <!--<svg viewbox width="1000" height="580" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle class="circle-outer" />
      <circle class="circle-inner" />
      <polygon points="0,0 0,200 1000,200" style="fill:#fff;" />
    </svg>
    -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h4>Body content must be positioned right
```

Note: obviously you will want to change the settings for type sizes to suit your particular use case. I just made them relative to the viewport so that it is responsive.

Also, there is some confusion I think between whether it is essential for the hero to cover the full width or for the min height to be set. Of course revert to that if that is what is required, the circles will just be in a different place relative to the apples and some of the image may disappear.

Comment: @A Haworth - Many thanks for the post. One other issue to note is that the hero content (h1, p, btn, etc.), which takes up much more space that depicted in the screenshot, needs to also appear on top of the white triangle. When I add content there, the content flows beneath the white triangle.

Comment: Ah, I did not pick that up from the question. Perhaps you could edit the code in your question to indicate that requirement. I would put the apples on a pseudo element and clip that rather than the actual element therefore.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of the triangle is 99, meaning it will be on top all other content in the page that has no z-index or z-index greater than 99. So just set the z-index to -1.
And besides, there's nothing like hero-triagle in your html, it's not the hero-triagle that's affecting your code, if I'm seeing the right thing here, it's the clip-path in the element, comments it out and see the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand though. Are you suggesting adding the z-index of -1 to the circles so that the triangle can properly overlay the circles. That's what I'm trying to accomplish here: https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/zYjgVpa?editors=1100

Comment: https://codepen.io/tunde-blades/pen/dyKbdeJ